# Is there a dedicated application for the purpose of running programs written in JS (+HTML/CSS) that can be redistributable freely?

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks, open-source

I'm wondering if there's a dedicated application for the purpose of running programs written in JS (+HTML/CSS) that can be redistributable freely with any such program.

My project may grow into something bigger and it just can't simply depend on an internet browser (also, I'm not sure about the security of running a JS app which doesn't connect to the internet in an internet-ready browser).

I've read that one must use AJAX to manage files through JS in a web browser, but are there any frameworks which allow to run JS code with all file management permissions?

Basically, I'm looking for the framework that web browsers use to show webpages - the very essence of a browser. What are the better alternatives that could meet my requirements?

Comment: I belive you can use IEBrowser control in .NET to make a simulated browser to run local pages, so it looks more like it's embedded into your software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like node.js? [Node](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Couldn't have found it by myself. As a beginner, I found reading/following this tutorial to be somewhat useful: http://www.nodebeginner.org